# Relogin basic auth popup during login

Tags: java, authentication, session-cookies, basic-authentication

I have web application developed using java/j2ee and have enable basic authentication, its working fine. But there is one issue in the following below situation.

```
 - Opened the same application in 2 different tabs.
 - During login i am switching/back to this applications.
 - But again it will ask for login credentials(basic authentication popup is coming)
```

Don't no what causing this issue? Any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution for the above issue:**

Both application contains the same `JSESSIONID` key which is getting conflict when i switching the tabs. I solved this by giving the unique `JSESSIONID` key name for each application

```
App1  -- JSESSIONID_app1:bqkdsfasjfd79879jlkjadf
App2  -- JSESSIONID_app2:adfkjasf8908098kj987jkl
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty common even in single page application that the user will want to use multiple tabs. The afordmentioned security enahncment of saving the token in the sessionStorage will create some bad UX in the form of requesting the user to re-login with every tab he opens. Right, **sessionStorage is not shared across tabs**.

The way I solved it is by using localStorage events. 
When a user opens a new tab, we first ask any other tab that is opened if he already have the sessionStorage for us. If any other tab is opened it’ll send us the sessionStorage through localStorage event, we’ll duplicate that into the sessionStorage. 
The sessionStorage data will not stay in the localStorage, not even for 1 millisecond as it being deleted in the same call. **The data is shared through the event payload and not the localStorage itself.**

If you want more information on this just tryout reading

https://blog.guya.net/2015/06/12/sharing-sessionstorage-between-tabs-for-secure-multi-tab-authentication/